# Using javaconfig to create regions in gemfire

Tags: gemfire, spring-data-gemfire

Is it possible to do Javaconfig i.e annotations in spring instead of xml to create client regions in Spring gemfire?

I need to plug in cache loader and cache writer also to the regions created...how is that possible to do?

I want to perform the client pool configuration as well..How is that possible?

Answer (score 1):

There is a good example of this in the [spring.io guides](http://spring.io/guides/gs/accessing-data-gemfire/). However, GemFire APIs are factories, wrapped by Spring FactoryBeans in Spring Data Gemfire, so I find XML actually more straightforward for configuring Cache and Regions.

Comment: The example is creating local regions...how can I create a client region in a distributed environment?

Answer (score 1):

Regarding... "how can I create a client region in a distributed environment?"

In the same way the Spring IO guides demonstrate Regions defined in a peer cache on a GemFire Server, something similar to...

```
@Bean
public ClientRegionFactoryBean<Long, Customer> clientRegion(ClientCache clientCache) {
    return new ClientRegionFactoryBean() {
        {
            setCache(clientCache);
            setName("Customers");
            setShortcut(ClientRegionShortcut.CACHING_PROXY);  // Or just PROXY if the client is not required to store data, or perhaps another shortcut type.
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

Disclaimer, I did not test this code snippet, so it may need minor tweaking along with additional configuration as necessary by the application.

You of course, will defined a  along with a Pool in your Spring config, or use the  element abstraction on the client-side.